How to unzip files on external HD, zipped in Windows 10?
Before installing Ubuntu 24.04 by wiping Windows 10 HD, I backed up personal files to an external SSD, using whatever zipping Windows 10 was offering. Now, trying to unzip into  Ubuntu, DISKS sees the SSHD, but says, "contents unknown".
$ lsblk -ape7 -o+PARTLABEL,LABEL
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
                                                    PARTLABEL LABEL
/dev/sda           8:0    0  7.3T  0 disk                     
└─/dev/sda1        8:1    0  7.3T  0 part                     Data8
...
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS PARTLABEL                    LABEL
/dev/sda
          8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk                                          
├─/dev/sda1
│         8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi                                
└─/dev/sda2
          8:2    0 930.5G  0 part /                                        
/dev/sdb
          8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk                                          
├─/dev/sdb1
│         8:17   0    16M  0 part             Microsoft reserved partition 
└─/dev/sdb2
          8:18   0 465.7G  0 part             Storage pool                 
/dev/sr0
         11:0    1  1024M  0 rom                                           
NAME: command not found
PARTLABEL: command not found
bash: /dev/sda: Permission denied
bash: └─/dev/sda1: No such file or directory
...: command not found

Then:
$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda2
Error mounting /dev/sda2: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Error.AlreadyMounted: Device /dev/sda2 is already mounted at `/'.

Already mounted?

How did you format the external SSHD? Open the app Disks in Ubuntu. Select the external drive from the right panel. Take a screenshot. Edit your question and add the screenshot.

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

It sounds like you are trying to unzip the block device on which you saved the zip files rather than the zip files themselves - you need to mount the block device first to access the files

If you end up to need Windows, the BEST option is to use e.g. Virtualbox and install Windows in a VM.

Waltinator:
Computer had been running Win10. The SSHD had been used for external auto backup, using Win10 native backup system. The SSHD had become full some time ago, PC was giving warnings about being unable to complete backups. I decided to get out of Microsoft/Google, but before installing Ubuntu 24.04 with the wipe-it-all-and-start-fresh option, I wiped the SSHD and loaded it with all personal files, responding affermative when offered to compress the files. Also, before wiping Win10, I was able to read a sample of files, using Winzip utility, just to make sure the files were accessable.

steeldriver:
Please explain mounting the block device.

Hannu:
Thanks for the tip about Virtualbox.
Would this be the sequence?  Download Virtualbox / Download Win10 / Use Winzip on Win10 to unzip the files on the SSHD / Be able tothen open them in Ubuntu.

Working in Terminal is a bit much for me, the newcomer. Now I am going to try opening the SSHD on a Win11 laptop, unzipping files, copy files to a USB stick, open and save on the Ubuntu computer. Should work. Wish me luck!

Well, that didn't work. Win11 PC only recognized 32GB out of 500GB.
Back to trying to get Ubunto to read it. At least Ubuntu could see that it is 500GB, even thoughnot reading it.

After you have connected the drive in an appropriate way,
you need to find out which block device your disk is located at
$ lsblk -ape7 -o+PARTLABEL,LABEL
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
                                                    PARTLABEL LABEL
/dev/sda           8:0    0  7.3T  0 disk                     
└─/dev/sda1        8:1    0  7.3T  0 part                     Data8
...

Then you can mount it, "system-style" by:
$ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda1
Mounted /dev/sda1 at /media/hannu/Data8

... and access the files in /media/hannu/Data8/
When you're done, ALWAYS do "Eject" (unmount) it, before removing it physically:
$ udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sda1
Unmounted /dev/sda1.


$ sudo apt install 7zip
...

to install 7zip, and
$ 7z --help | less 

... to read how to use it.
(h in the reader will display keys to direct it, q to quit)
